# Probability Density Function of Piecewise Differentiable Cummulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability, density-function

consider following piecewise cdf. It is continuous but not differentiable at just $2$ points. My question is it *valid* to take piecewise derivative of cdf and call it pdf.

$ G(x) =  \begin{cases} 
        \dfrac{x}{3 *0.1} .    & 0 < x    \leq 0.1 \\
        \dfrac{x - 0.1}{3 *(0.6 - 0.1) } + \frac{1}{3}  &  0.1 < x   \leq 0.6\\
     \dfrac{x - 0.6}{3* (0.9 - 0.6) } + \frac{2}{3}  &  0.6 < x   \leq 0.9\\
   \end{cases}
$

$ g(x) =  \begin{cases} 
        \dfrac{1}{3 *0.1} .    & 0 < x    \leq 0.1 \\
        \dfrac{1}{3 *(0.6 - 0.1) }   &  0.1 < x   \leq 0.6\\
     \dfrac{1 }{3* (0.9 - 0.6) }   &  0.6 < x   \leq 0.9\\
   \end{cases}
$

My guess is that it is okay because I think $g$ satisfies following $$\int_a^b g(x) = G(b) - G(a)$$ for all $0<a<b<0.9$ because  Riemann Integral doesn't depend on values at finite number of points.I am asking because I haven't studied probability rigorously and I want to make sure my guess is correct.Also, Please don't involve any measure theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. For example, function $p(x) = \begin{cases}
1,\ x \in [0, 1]\\
0,\ x \notin [0, 1]
\end{cases}$ is density function of uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ even though it's CDF is not-differentiable in $0$ or $1$.

(formally, PDF is defined up to measure zero, although we usually try to find "most continuous" one)